# Ubuntu 19.10 NVidia drivers issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.10

Context: my laptop was running perfectly for months, then yesterday while I was playing a game on steam, it just rebooted all of a sudden and then after that it didn't even recognized the NVidia drivers, I couldn't see the graphics card drivers in the Software and Updates settings or ubuntu-drivers devices. I tried reainstalling the drivers but still have issues.

Laptop:
Dell xps 9570
NVidia GTX 1050 ti

Some commands for more info:

```
alex@alex:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:3b:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d00002526sv00008086sd00000014bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
model    : Wireless-AC 9260
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Csv00001028sd0000087Cbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

alex@alex:~$ 

alex@alex:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
[sudo] password for alex: 
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                               
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                           
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                         
Hit:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                                                       
Hit:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease                                              
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                               
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                          
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                             
Hit:10 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                                            
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                  
Hit:12 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org eoan InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvidia-common-435 linux-headers-5.3.0-40 linux-headers-5.3.0-40-generic linux-image-5.3.0-40-generic
  linux-modules-5.3.0-40-generic linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-40-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-keyring
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 28.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 python3-keyring all 18.0.1-1ubuntu1 [28.6 kB]
Fetched 28.6 kB in 0s (131 kB/s)         
(Reading database ... 289354 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-keyring_18.0.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-keyring (18.0.1-1ubuntu1) over (18.0.1-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-dkms-440 (440.64-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-440.64 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 440.64
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-440.64 DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-45-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.3.0-45-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-440.0.crash'
Error! Application of patch disable_fstack-clash-protection_fcf-protection.patch failed.
Check /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.64/build/ for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-440 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-440 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Setting up python3-keyring (18.0.1-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-440:
 nvidia-driver-440 depends on nvidia-dkms-440 (= 440.64-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.2); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-440 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-440 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing tri
ggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.133ubuntu10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-45-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p4
I: (UUID=4ef37681-250c-4d75-954b-c8cf78fd5e65)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-440
 nvidia-driver-440
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
alex@alex:~$
```

Thanks